# Use Automapper in ITypeConverter

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm upgrading AutoMapper in a project, converting from the static `Mapper.CreateMap` to the new way and injecting a `IMapper` where I need to map.

This is going great except for one use case. I have several `ITypeConverter`s for complex mapping which are using the `Mapper.Map` function. How can I fix this? Below is the code I'm using at the moment.

The static `Mapper.Map` can't find my defined mappings because the're not being created using the static method.

```
public partial class ApplicationMappingsProfile
{
    private void RegisterMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<Application, AppDto>()
            .ConvertUsing<ApplicationTypeConverter>();
    }
}

private class ApplicationTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<App, AppDto>
{
    public AppDto Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var src = context.SourceValue as App;
        if (src == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var dto = Mapper.Map<App, AppDto>(src);
        dto.property = Mapper.Map<Property>(src.SomeProperty);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `ResolutionContext` contains a reference to the current Mapping engine. Switch the `Mapper.Map` with `context.Mapper.Map` and you're good to go.

```
public partial class ApplicationMappingsProfile
{
    private void RegisterMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<Application, AppDto>()
            .ConvertUsing<ApplicationTypeConverter>();
    }
}

private class ApplicationTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<App, AppDto>
{
    public AppDto Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var src = context.SourceValue as App;
        if (src == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var dto = Mapper.Map<App, AppDto>(src);
        dto.property = context.Mapper.Map<Property>(src.SomeProperty);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use IMapper instance inside of ctor?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic inject it?

Comment: The syntax has changed in v6 - more info here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Custom-type-converters.md